# adjusted wald intervall

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I m trying to derive the adjusted-wald-CI (agresti coull intervall) which is quite similar to the standardwald intervall only for the estimator where we add 2 success and 2 failure
$$\hat{p}=\frac{\sum X_i  + 2}{n+4}$$
anyone has idea why it performs so much better than the original one and how does one prove , using $\tilde{p}$ as point estimate, that it is still an asymptotic CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y = \sum X_i$ be the number of successes observed in $n$ Bernoulli trials, the unknown probability of success is $p$, where $0 < p < 1$.

Consider the test of the null hypothesis $H_0: p = p_0$ against 
the two-sided alternative $H_a: p \ne p_0.$

Assuming that $n$ is sufficiently large and $p$ is sufficiently
near $1/2$ that the normal approximation is suitable, a test
statistic 
$$ Z = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}},$$
where $\hat p = Y/n$ and we reject at the 5% level if $|Z| \ge 1.96.$

Often one can get a good two-sided confidence interval (CI) by 'inverting'
such a two-sided test. Here a 95% CI is the interval of values
$p_0$ that would $not$ lead to rejection of $H_0.$ Sometimes
one says the CI consists of 'acceptable' values $p = p_0.$

A naive attempt to invert the test (perhaps following the
procedure to get a t interval) would lead to the nonsense
interval.
$$ \hat p \pm 1.96 \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$$

This is a useless interval because the factor $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$
contains the unknown value $p.$ Essentially, the Wald interval
replaces unknown $p$ by the observed $\hat p$.

A more productive inversion is to solve the inequality $-1.96 < Z < 1.96$ for $p = p_0$ by squaring and using the quadratic formula. 
This gives rise to the well-known 'Wilson score CI' for $p$. (Search Google for many references.) This interval has been widely used in
advanced applications, but many elementary and intermediate
texts have preferred the Wald interval because it is considerably
simpler.

However, the Wald interval involves two approximations: (a) normal to binomial and (b) substitution of $p$ by $\hat p$. It has been
shown by computational studies that the actual coverage probability of
Wald intervals is unsatisfactorily smaller than the intended 95% for many
values of $p$--especially for $n$ smaller than several hundred.
The Wald interval is 'asymptotically' correct. This means it
becomes more accurate as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ But infinity is
'a long way out there' and the Wald interval is not satisfactory
for small or moderate $n$.

The Agresti-Coull interval is a simplified version of the Wilson
interval, valid $only$ for 95% confidence intervals. The formula for the Wilson interval
contains a $2$ and a $4$ and several instances of $z^* = 1.96$.
If we approximate $z^* \approx 2$, then some simplifications
occur, and a further simplification is to ignore a term that
is very small even for moderately large $n$. With these 'tricks'
the simplified Wilson interval becomes the Agresti-Coull interval.

The difference in coverage behavior between the Wilson and Agresti-Coull intervals is mainly quite small, and the simpler interval
has recently become very popular in statistics texts at the 
elementary and intermediate levels. A comprehensive review
article by Brown, Cai, and DasGupta (2001) illustrates coverage
probabilities for these and other styles of confidence intervals.

Here is a simple numerical example in R, illustrating the three styles
of confidence intervals discussed above.

```
 n = 50;  y = 43;  pm = c(-1,1);  c = 1.96
 p.hat = y/n
 round(p.hat + pm*c*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n), 3)      # Wald
 ## 0.764 0.956
 p.adj = (y+2)/(n+4)
 round(p.adj + pm*c*sqrt(p.adj*(1-p.adj)/(n+4)), 3)  # A-C
 ## 0.734 0.933
 pp = seq(0, 1, by=.0001);  z = (p.hat-pp)/sqrt(pp*(1-pp)/n)
 inv = pp[abs(z)<=1.96]
 round(c(min(inv), max(inv)), 3)                     # Wilson
 ## 0.738 0.930
```

Comment: thx bro , i didn t get an E-mail though telling me i had a response , that s why i didn t get it till now

Comment: applying the CLT on $\tilde{p}$ i get $\lim_{n \to \infty}{P \left(\frac{(n+4)}{n}\tilde{p} -z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{2}{n} \leq  p \leq \frac{(n+4)}{n}\tilde{p} + z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{2}{n} \right)} = 1-\alpha$  does it make sense to say that inside the limit $(\frac{(n+4)}{n}\tilde{p}$ and $\frac{2}{n}$ converges respectively to $\tilde{p}$ and 0 so that we become

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{P \left(\tilde{p} -z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})}}{\sqrt{n}}   \leq p \leq \tilde{p} + z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})}}{\sqrt{n}}  \right)} = 1-\alpha$

Comment: These limiting expressions both seem OK, but they have little to do with the style of CI you're calling 'adjusted Wald'. Asymptotically (that is, in the limit) Wald doesn't need adjusting. For very large n Wald is essentially exact. Adjustment is needed for small n where estimation of p in the standard error is problematic. $\hat p = (X + 2)/(n + 4)$ results in a good approx to Wilson, which is nearly exact when normal approx applies (esp. used when n is in dozens or low hundreds).

Comment: in germany wald never becomes exact , cuz exact is $P (U \leq p \leq O)\geq 1-\alpha$ for every p , where wald is based on the CLT (asymptotically) , that s why i have to prove the asympticall behaviour for the AC intervall , can i go from the first intervall that i have written  to the second only saying $\tilde{p}$ is consistent

Comment: Then please edit your question to explain exactly what your definitions are and exactly what your goal is. To me your last comment seems orthogonal to your original question.

Comment: done. sry fot that , but i made some progress since than , that s why my question involved a little

Comment: As $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $(x + 2)/(n + 4) \sim x/n.$

Comment: Just glad you figured it out. But FYI: Click on 'check' symbol next to number to accept (only one answer to a question). Also, if you have enough 'reputation' points, you can click on up-arrow to up-vote (as many answers as you think appropriate, or even answers to questions you didn't ask). Also, down-arrow to down-vote (but down voting costs reputation points).